# How to repair corrupted table 'global_priv' in localhost xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I encountered a problem in my xampp phpmyadmin i search for it but didn't find solution here is a screenshot of it.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run from the command line

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases
```

this will check all databases, but it is better to check them all

Comment: In cmd it says mysqlcheck  is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I found a simple solution:

1. Run XAMPP Web Server
2. Go to Folder\xampp\mysql\bin
3. Run mysql_upgrade.exe
4. RESTART XAMP & ENJOY

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Xampp Web Server

go to the

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin

Add this command

mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases

Comment: This helped me quickly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open XAMPP Control Panel
2. Click Shell Button
3. Run This Command

   `mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases`